# How to hide element when AdminLTE sidebar is collapsed?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, adminlte

I'm using AdminLTE theme (Bootstrap). I have some custom elements on the sidebar. I want to hide them when the sidebar is collapsed. Is there some specific class to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the collapse event like this:

```
$(document).on('expanded.pushMenu', function () {
    $('.your-special-element').show();
}).on('collapsed.pushMenu', function(){
    $('.your-special-element').hide();
});
```

Instead of show and hide it looks nicer if you use fadeOut and fadeIn